# getting answer from 5 random multiple choice in php

Tags: php

I am trying to build a Web Application that generate 5 random question from the database along with 4 possible answers. Each question come up with their own ID. I have stuck when the user click the submit button, it will direct to result.php page where it shows the number of the right answers. I dont know how to match the question ID with the answer in database since there are 5 questions at the same time (5 forms). Here is what i've tried so far

```
            <script>
    function sender() {
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    document.forms["form2"].submit();
    document.forms["form3"].submit();
    document.forms["form4"].submit();
    document.forms["form5"].submit();
    return true;
    }
    </script>
    <?php

    include('db.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quizzes ORDER BY rand() limit 5";   
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '
    <form id="form'.$i.'" action="result.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr><td>'.$data['content'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="a">'.$data['a'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="b">'.$data['b'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="c">'.$data['c'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="d">'.$data['d'].'</td></tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    ';

    }}
    echo '
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=javascript:sender()>
    ';

?>
```

Comment: you need to combine all the forms into one, just put the form tag above the while loop, you also need to change the name attribute in each radio option to be specific to that set of multiple choice (i.e. `name="option-'.$i.'"`)

Comment: @iamde_coder i understand your idea. But how to generate the $i for each question. Btw, i tried to put the form tag above the while loop but in the end it still get 5 form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the Herdoc syntax so I use `MYSQL_NUM` in the `mysql_fetch_array`

Then add the question ID to the name of the radio button

If the questions are numbered in a column other than id use that instead  e.g.

```
`SELECT `number`,`
```

.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`,`content`,`a`,`b`,`c`,`d` FROM quizzes ORDER BY rand() limit 5";   
mysql_query($sql);
echo '<form action="result.php" method="post"><div>';
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)){
 echo <<<EOF
<table><tr><td>$data[1]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="a">$data[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="b">$data[3]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="c">$data[4]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="d">$data[5]</td></tr></table>
EOF;
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></form>';
```

---

### Get Results:

To get the submitted answers your result.php should start like this:

```
foreach $_POST as $key => $value){
  if(substr($key,0,6) == 'option`){
    $id = intval(substr($key,6));
    $answers[$id] = $value;
  }
}
var_export($answers);
```

**If your question id following 'option' is not all numeric,** remove the `intval()`

**Then look up question for each answer:**

```
foreach($answers as $id => $answer){
  $sql = "SELECT .... WHERE `id` = $id"; //If non-numeric, add single quotes '$id'
}
```

### Update

This should be how your basic form will look:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post"><div>

<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option1" value="a">Answer A</td></tr>
 ...
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option5" value="a">Answer D</td></tr>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></form>
```

The `<form>`  before the `<input type="submit" />` 
The  after the submit

Most likely problem is an unclosed set of double quotes
Make sure all double quotes are closed especially these: `"result.php"`, including the name and value of each radio button.

If you right click the form and choose "Inspect Element" you will see:

[image]

The above is from FireFox Inspector

When you click the right facing arrow on the `<form>`

You should then see:

```
<form
  <div></div>
</form
```

**You should always run your web pages through the W3C HTML Markup Validator:**

[W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I just tried it an it made a POST request for /result.php.  From the HTTP Request Header: `POST /result.php HTTP/1.1`.  What happens when you click submit?
`

Comment: Sorry I know what my mistake is. I have marked your answer. Can i ask 1 one question that in the result.php, how can we pass the "option$data[0]" in order to link with the answer in database

Comment: I changed the existing `$answer` to plural `$answers`.

Comment: `MYSQL_QUERY` needs to be *avoided*.

Comment: Don't tell me it's the OP's code. But seeing you brought it up I will humbly disagree. A lot of the real life work I do is for a medical laboratory.  My work must be HIPAA compliant or I get fined $50,000+.  Yes PHP has depreciated MSQL, but I have 100% control of what version of PHP and mySQL I run.  I am going with the one with no security vulnerabilities. MSQLi, is a work in progress and has recently had some very sever security issues.  Leading Edge?  More like Bleeding Edge.  Thank you but I staying away from PHP Extensions that will get me fined for exposing confidential patient records

Comment: Thank you for all the helping then. I solved my problem thanks to your clearly advises. I'm a beginner in PHP so this maybe a little bit higher level to me and i have to waste your time asking stupid questions a lot. You are a very nice teacher. Thank you once again

Comment: You are very welcome.    Send me a link when you get it up and running.  Ask away, that's why I'm here.